# MATLAB: Change the contour line label from number to string

Tags: string, matlab, contour

This code plots three contour lines for 5-σ,4-σ and 3-σ for the following bivariate normal distribution. Is it possible to change the the contour line labels from numbers (probability values) to strings (i.e. {'5-σ', '4-σ' '3-σ'}) ?

```
mu = [2 3];
Sigma = [1 1];
x1 = -4:.2:8; x2 = -3:.2:9;
[X1,X2] = meshgrid(x1,x2);
F = mvnpdf([X1(:) X2(:)],mu,Sigma);
F = reshape(F,length(x2),length(x1));
%Values drawn from a normal distribution are 
%5-σ,4-σ and 3-σ awayfrom the mean
TL=1-erf([5 4 3]/sqrt(2));             
[C,h]=contour(x1,x2,F,TL,'ShowText','on');
```

I tried a solution given in a similar post [How To Put String Labels on Contours for Contour Plots in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16724240/how-to-put-string-labels-on-contours-for-contour-plots-in-matlab) and got this MATLAB warning message:

> Warning: Text handle output is not supported for managed labels

Comment: I tried this one but did not work for me. I still get numbers and not strings! I got this warning message:Warning: Text handle output is not supported for managed labels.

Comment: @BERKO then edit your question with what you tried.

Comment: How'd you implement that solution?